# Script automatizado Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, bash, script, cpanel

Estoy en un proyecto en el que necesito crear un script que automatice la instalación en diferentes.

El código:

```html
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/luis/public_html/1/wordpress/

read to_print

cp -R wp-signup.php wp-login.php wp-config-sample.php license.txt xmlrpc.php wp-settings.php wp-cron.php wp-load.php wp-activate.php wp-comments-post.php licencia.txt wp-trackback.php wp-links-opml.php wp-mail.php index.php readme.html wp-blog-header.php /home/luis/public_html/$to_print/

cp -R /home/luis/public_html/1/wordpress/wp-admin/ /home/luis/public_html/1/wordpress/wp-includes/ /home/luis/public_html/1/wordpress/wp-content/ /home/luis/public_html/$to_print/
```

Lo que me gustaría es poder coger la variable de un CSV o similar, en vez de escribirla. Por ahora lo que hace es copiar Wordpress de forma local y llevarlo a la carpeta del dominio pero tengo que definir el dominio en el script.

Nótese que estoy aprendiendo !

Comment: Te refieres a que tienes que ingresar la ruta local de destino copiar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que lo que quieres es hacer un script que copie un directorio que contiene la colección de archivos de wordpress como para empezar una instalación limpia en un directorio destino, y quieres evitar ingresar uno a uno los directorios destinos, puedes tener, por ejemplo, un archivo `directorios.txt`

```
juanito
pedrito
jorgito
dieguito
```

(nótese, el archivo **debe tener una línea en blanco al final** o no se leerá el último registro)

> ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.21.2 Streams
>
> A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into
>   lines, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a
>   terminating new-line character.

Ahora tu script en bash lee línea por línea de ese archivo:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="directorios.txt"
while read -r subdirectorio
do
  # rsync -avzr /home/luis/public_html/1/wordpress/ /home/luis/public_html/$subdirectorio/
  echo "rsync -avzr /home/luis/public_html/1/wordpress/ /home/luis/public_html/$subdirectorio/"
done < "$input"
```

La ruta del subdirectorio la puse en duro. Eso podrías perfeccionarlo. Lo importante es que va copiando el contenido de la fuente ejecutando

```
rsync -avzr /home/luis/public_html/1/wordpress/ /home/luis/public_html/juanito/
rsync -avzr /home/luis/public_html/1/wordpress/ /home/luis/public_html/pedrito/
rsync -avzr /home/luis/public_html/1/wordpress/ /home/luis/public_html/jorgito/
rsync -avzr /home/luis/public_html/1/wordpress/ /home/luis/public_html/dieguito/
```

Me pareció más eficiente usar `rsync` que poner los archivos explícitamente.

En el ejemplo dejé el comando comentado y a cambio puse un `echo` de lo que haría el comando.

Comment: No, utilizar rsync no copia los archivos. Si lo pongo directamente en terminal si pero con bash no

Comment: pero te fijaste que en mi ejemplo puse un `echo` en vez del comando real? Comenta esa línea y descomenta la que está justo arriba